# How to iterate all tokens with for in bat file?

Tags: batch-file

This is my code:

```
set str=one.two.three.four
for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%a in ("%str%") do ECHO "%%a "
```

I want to iterate all tokens without delimiter, so, in the example I need to get `one two three four`. But I get `"one.two.three.four "`. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You could replace your second line with this: `echo %str:.= %`

Comment: @Compo Thank you very much. It works, but could you explain this code?

Comment: That will replace all `.`s with spaces. The general syntax is `%variable_name:old_substring=new_substring%`

Comment: @SomethingDark Thank you for your explanation. But I need a way to get all tokens, to use them later, for example for string concat. I just need `pure` splits without delimiter in loop. Is it possible to do?

Comment: If you replace the periods with spaces, a regular `for` loop (with no other options) will treat it like a list of things to loop over. For example, `for %%A in (%str:.= %) do echo %%A` will echo `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four` on separate lines because it processes them one at a time.

Comment: @SomethingDark Yes, thank you! This is what I need. If make an answer I will accept it.